# Do zoomable graphs need different data sets for every zoom level?

Tags: d3.js

Say you have a bar chart graphing the number of page views based on the day of the month it was viewed. You could represent the data like so:

```
var data = [ { date: '05-05-2011', count: 6 }, { date: '05-06-2011', count: 10 } ... ]
```

The bar chart might look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbhQR.png

Now say you want to "zoom out" of this chart and see views by month. The chart might look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouHrb.png

My question: does the data need to change such that it would be like

```
var data = [ { date: '05-2011', count: 100 }, { date: '06-2011', count: 131 } ... ]
```

or does d3 have some capability to scale the bars based on the more fine-grained data?

Comment: No you use the same dataset regardless of the zoom

Comment: Is it possible to make meaningful bar charts with very specific data at any domain scale? For example if my data is at the hourly level it might be {date: '05-07-2011-7', count: 2}. Meaning that there were 2 views at the 7th hour on 05-07-2011. But how do I "combine" all of the 05-07 hours into a single 05-07 bar without adding up the counts myself? Does d3 handle this in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

The code that does the re-sampling is in this section:

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select("path").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

Apologies if this is not exactly what you was looking for!

Comment: Technically it's not even resampling, it's just adjusting the domain -- you're selecting what parts of the data to show, not changing the data.

Comment: Right, this adjusts the scale of the axis which I've seen. But the problem with this graph is that you can brush a small enough area so that you get the hours on the x-axis even though the data is not specific enough to matter at that level.